# is there any way to pass vuejs object to laravel controller?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, vue.js

I have a Vue component and it has an object, such as -

```
dataObj = [{id:1,name:'sanaulla'},{id:1,name:'parvez'}]
```

But, when I send a post request to the Laravel Controller by like this -

```
axios.post("/api/directory",this.dataObj)
```

It's not a from it's just a js object!
From the controller, I like as below -

```
{[{id:1,name:'sanaulla'},{id:1,name:'parvez'},'/api/directory']}
```

So, how can I send this object as JSON to the Laravel controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you need to pass the whole object as a field you have to pass it as a string and then use json_decode on the controller.

Example using axios for the request:

```
axios.post("your_endpoint",
{your_object_field_name: JSON.stringify(your_object)}).then(res => {
//handle response
})
```

on the controller:

```
public function yourControllerMethod(){
   $data = response()->validate('your_object_field_name','required|json'); //validate the field so it is in valid json format
   $jsonArray = json_decode($data); // here you have your json as a php object, pass true as second argument if you want an array (json_decode($data,true))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of POST for sending name and email

```
   //Variables
    data(){
      return{
        object:{
           name: null,
           email: null,
        }
     }
    }

    //In methods
    sendPost(){
       axios.post("http://url-route-exemple.com", this.object).then(result => {
         console.log(result.data); //return laravel
       })
    }
```

With this you can get the name and email data in the laravel standard (PHP)

```
//In controller.php
$name = $request->input("name");
$email = $request->input("email");
$jsonNameAndEmail = json_encode($request->all());
```